# Alexa Custom Skill - 2-way SSL

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

When Alexa's custom skill connects to a third-party application, is there any way to furnish an installed SSL-certificate on the request?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any need - the server provides the certificate for this type of 'asymmetric' security.  (I'm assuming you would be the client in an HTTPS link.)